# Простейшая задача на алгоритмизацию и SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Есть простейшая задача: Найти k-ое простое число.

Я без труда вспомнил алгоритм и начал писать, но через некоторое время появились проблемы.

Я заметил, что при запуске программа даже не спрашивает число на ввод. Это меня удивило и я полез отлаживать программу.

Мне сразу написали про SIGSEGV. Подобная ситуация некоторое время назад была с другой программой, но тогда я подумал, что просто криво написал код.

Что это может быть? Может ли быть с этим связано то, что некоторое время назад я устанавливал на винду драйвер для подключения ext, но в итоге восстанавливал home и root разделы?

Теперь немного технической информации:

- Дистрибутив: arch linux 64
- IDE:         qtCreator
- *.pro:       стандартный
- Компилятор:  gcc

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    const int mdl = 15485864;
    bool pr[mdl + 100];
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    pr[1] = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 15485864; i++)
        pr[i] = true;

    int dl = 2;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {   //---
        int j = dl * dl;
        pr[j] = false;
        for(j; j <= mdl; j += dl)
            pr[j] = false;
        //---
        if (i == 2)
            i = 3;
        else
            i += 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Там есть небольшие логические ошибки в коде, но суть не в них

Comment: Я конечно могу переписать на python/FreePascal, но было-бы неплохо найти тут проблему

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема у вас здесь:

```
const int mdl = 15485864;
bool pr[mdl + 100];
```

Данные такого объёма выделять на стеке нельзя, используйте `new`:

```
bool *pr = new bool[mdl+100]; // не забудьте потом освободить
```

Ещё одна мелочь, вот тут:

```
for(j; j <= mdl; j += dl)
```

или:

```
for(; j <= mdl; j += dl)
```

или (логичней, и тогда строка `int j = dl * dl;` не нужна):

```
for(int j = dl * dl;  j <= mdl; j += dl)
```

---

> данные какого объёма можно выделять на стеке

Стек вообще не предназначен для храннеия объёмных данных. Если компилятор выделяет для стека тот же мегабайт, то это не значит, что и вы можете выделять там этот мегабайт. Стек - рабочая лошадка, которая используется как явно (при объявлении локальных нестатических переменных), так и неявно. Например, при любом вызове функции. Как для передачи параметров, так и для организации самого вызова. То есть написали вы `func()` - уже задействовали стек. А если это рекурсивная функция, да ещё и с аргументами, и с какими-то локальными переменными... Так что к стеку относиться стоит бережно :)

Comment: Спасибо) Вы всё спасли. Надо будет почитать про то, данные какого объёма можно выделять на стеке, проблема была именно в этом. На мелочи обращу внимание, но они не критичны, это так, код на задачу которую нужно просто сдать

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, в стеке можно выделять не более того объёма, что указан в ключах компиляции при сборки приложения. Если ничего не указывать, то используется некоторое значение по умолчанию. Часто, это значение бывает равно 1-у мегабайту.

Answer (score -3):

Для начала у вас нету элементарных знаний работы с переменными. Я понимаю что вы только учитесь, но необходимо сначала самому попытаться разобраться прежде чем просить о помощи так как вы ничему не научитесь. 
ИЗ ЯВНЫХ ОШИБОК:

1) bool pr[mdl + 100]; превышен диапазон массива.

И вообще смысл строки не особо понятен. bool имеет всего 2 состояния если 0 ложь и все что выше нуля правда.

SIGSEGV - сама ошибка означает что прыгнуло на ломаный код если совсем просто. Делайте построчную отладку кода и разбирайтесь если вылетает на n-ой строке значит в этой строчке ошибка иногда может и выше.

Comment: (1) Это объявление. Нельзя превысить то, чего ещё нет. (2) Всё, что НЕ ноль — правда.  (3) Совет использовать отладчик это от силы комментарий, не тянет на решение.